# How to make background-image full-screen with html+css

Tags: html, css

I want to create background-image full-screen in HTML, and CSS I have set all properties for background image.
This is my background-image on folder.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I try to  do  this.

```css
<style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .background-image {
            background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="background-image"></div>

</body>
```

But I don't want the background-image on the top to hidden or cut, I want to display all background-image full-screen. As you can see, missing the text above. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you descripe. `background-size: cover` will strech the image to cover the full element.

Comment: Put the `background-image` class on the `<body>` tag that way it will be behind all your content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer tacoshy
I have try  to do this but whene i have done this my background image scrolling dow and up i don't want to scrolling.

Comment: its because of the default body margin, reset it with `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: @tacoshy i try also to remove margin and padding but result is the same I don't think is this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `background-size: contain` instead of `cover`. That way the image will expand to fill the avialable space but will not be cut. This will leave empty spaces around the image.

If you want to have the gradient background to fill the whole area (so you don't have empty spaces) you could use 2 backgrounds:

- one with the gradient with `background-size: cover`
- one where you cut out the subject of the picture (with Photoshop or a similar program) and with `background-size: contain`

Edit:

I made an example with a css gradient. The kitten should be the subject. I gave it at fixed height (400px) in stead of contain, but on smaller screens it will cut the kitty. If you don't want sliced kitten, you can change the `400px` in the example below to `contain`.

```css
#full-screen {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background:
        center / 400px url(https://placekitten.com/400/400) no-repeat,
        radial-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="full-screen">
    </div>
</body>
```

For more technical details and options you can consult the documentation at developer.mozilla.org, that's a great resource:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient()

Comment: Thanks I try to use two background images one background-size: cover; 
and another background-size: contain; after that when 
I make inspect element win rule: background-size: contain; 
tha background image exapnade to fill space not be cut on the top, 
but leave space in the left and right. How to solve this?